# How can I disable/hide the grouping of variables in vscode-python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Recently the ms-python extension ([v2020.5.86806](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases/tag/2020.5.86806)) for vscode implements grouping of variables in the debug console/variable explorer.

They appear as:

```
<object>
  > special variables
  > function variables
```

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

EDIT: Screenshot added:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no single flag to revert to old behavior, but you can fine-tune it on a per-group basis in your launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ...,
            "module": ...,
            ...
            "variablePresentation": {
                "all": "inline",
                "class": "group",
                "function": "hide",
                "protected": ...,
                "special": ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

"all" applies to all groups, and sets the default that can be overridden as needed; other group names are self-explanatory. For values, "group" is the default behavior, "hide" removes those variables entirely, and "inline" places them without grouping.

**Note that the VSCode JSON schema hasn't been updated to reflect this yet**, so you'll get squiggles when editing. It'll still work, though.

Comment: You might draw some attention to launch.json as people might try to configure this in settings.json.

Comment: Where exactly in the launch.json this goes? I added it to configurations, and it says `Property variablePresentation is not allowed.`.

Comment: @Ashark: in the top level, so next to `version` and `configurations`, etc.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12373

Comment: @Ashark it also says `Property variablePresentation is not allowed` for me but just do it anyway. It works

Comment: @Ashark top level did not work for me, I had to put it in the `"configurations"` list, at the same level as `"name"` and `"module"` as shown in the screenshot answered by @pavel-minaev