# VS Code debugpy hiding special and function variables via variablePresentation in launch.json does not work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, debugpy

Other threads have suggested editing the launch.json debugpy configuration to edit the way cluttering variables are presented by adding variablePresentation:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "variablePresentation": {
                "function": "hide",
                "special": "hide",
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

This was suggested here:
[How can I disable/hide the grouping of variables in vscode-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62346091/how-can-i-disable-hide-the-grouping-of-variables-in-vscode-python)

However, this produces no effect. This makes it somewhat cumbersome when working on larger projects. Running:

debugpy version: 1.6.6
OS and version: Windows 10 Enterprise, version 21H2
Python version : 3.9.16, conda distribution
VS Code, version: 1.76.1 (user setup)

Just wanted a sanity check to see if there is something obviously wrong :)

Tried to debug a currently active Python file. Expected cluttering variables to be not displayed. This did not happen - config edit resulted in no change from default behavious.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12373